# Recommended Wireless Access Point Hardware

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm looking to install WiFi in one of our locations. We are going to need about 3 or 4 Wireless Access Points. So I'm looking for a product recommendation. The requirements are:

- Easy to install, can install directly into switch but also into a
  free network port in other areas.
- Easy to manage, ideally each WAP could be managed from one interface and create one coherent network. Rather than having to configure each one using a separate admin interface.
- Wall mountable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for a Cisco WAP. As long as you keep the SSID and channels the same they support roaming via 802.11F

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://www.pcengines.ch/ for hardware.  The ALIX boards support a wide range of software, so you're likely to find something which meets your administrative needs:

http://www.pcengines.ch/alix.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've made VERY good experience with **Mikrotik** access points. They are based on Linux and are capable of everything (WLAN (anything you can dream of) - you can extend the feature with different cards, BGP, MPLS, switching (with a special switch chip), scripting (alarms), hotspot feature ...).
Take a look at:

- http://www.mikrotik.com
- http://www.routerboard.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out the offerings of Ubiquiti Networks. Their UniFi line might just be what you are looking for, since it is a product recomendation you require. Easy to install and configure, ridiculously affordable, centrally managed from a visual web-gui and feature-packed. You can choose between 4 indoor models and one outdoor with external antennae. They are very reliable, to the extent of my knowledge, and offer seamless hand-overs for devices between APs. Also, the Controller software is very lightweight, runs on everything (some have tried compiling it for ARM).